# Debugging a specefic akka actor "line-by-line" in IDE?

Tags: scala, debugging, akka, actor

Is there a way to debug an akka actor line-by-line in an IDE (Jetbrains IDEA)?
I use logging for see life-cycles and ... but can I have some other standard tools (e.g watch, evaluate a variable, ...) for one actor or object or function in IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just start SBT in debug mode by exporting the options:

`SBT_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n"`

And setup a [remote debugging session in idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) and you can debug with breakpoints, watches e.t.c. as normal.